# List comprehension expression showing none value insted of sublist

Tags: python, list, list-comprehension

I am learning list comprehension and it is very fast, But I am trying to insert the value into sublist and it is showing `None` for that sublist. Here is I am trying,

```
def tester(lst):
      print [ x if x%2 else x*100 for x in range(1, 10) ] # It is working
      #output: [1, 200, 3, 400, 5, 600, 7, 800, 9]
      print [ls.insert(2,"Null") for ls in lst]
      #output: [None, None]


lst = [['a','c','d'],['1','2','3']]

tester(lst)
```

Why it is showing `[None, None]` ? and Why it is not showing `[['a','c','d', 'Null'],['1','2','3', 'Null']]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`list.insert` modifies the list in-place and returns `None`.

```
>>> lis = range(5)
>>> repr(lis.insert(2, 'null')) # returns None
'None'
>>> lis                         # But the list is affected.
[0, 1, 'null', 2, 3, 4]
```

Use a simple for-loop here:

```
for ls in lst:
    ls.insert(2, "Null")
```

You can do it with a list-comprehension too, but I'd prefer the normal loop version:

```
>>> lst = [range(5) for _ in range(5)]
>>> [ls for ls in lst if not ls.insert(2, 'null')]
[[0, 1, 'null', 2, 3, 4], [0, 1, 'null', 2, 3, 4], [0, 1, 'null', 2, 3, 4], [0, 1, 'null', 2, 3, 4], [0, 1, 'null', 2, 3, 4]]
```

Here when the if-condition is checked the item is inserted to the current list, and as `list.insert` returns `None`, `not None` is always `True`.

**Update:**

To update the list objects based on conditions you need to use a ternary expression:

```
>>> lst = [['a','c','d'],['1','2','3'], [1, 2, 3, 4]]
>>> [ls if (len(ls) == 3 and not ls.insert(2, 'null')) else ls for ls in lst]
[['a', 'c', 'null', 'd'], ['1', '2', 'null', '3'], [1, 2, 3, 4]]
```

Comment: +1 for a simple for-loop. If you use a list comprehension & discard the resulting list, you're doing it wrong.

Comment: @Ashwini Chaudhary thanks for your time answer the question, When I try this `[ls for ls in lst if (len(ls)==3) ls.insert(2,"Null")]`, But the error was raised.

Comment: @codeimplementer You need to use `and` there: `if len(ls)==3 and not ls.insert(2,"Null")`

Comment: @codeimplementer I've updated my answer, I guess that is what you're looking for.